# How to convert point text to geometry

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have installed postgis in my DB. Now i have 1 regions in my DB like ((-79.4609576808001,43.9726680183837))
 I want this region to convert to geometry type. I have searched on google and found that St_geomfromText will convert text to geometry type.

my query is as follows:

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(region,4326) from "erpAssets";
```

But it is giving error it is saying that no function matches for st_geomfromtext

Comment: Is '((-79.4609576808001,43.9726680183837))' an example entry? It looks like the documentation is expecting a geometry type in front of the point values. So it may need 'POINT' to be in the string. For example, 'SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.064544 42.28787)');'

Comment: yes it is an example entry. how should i do it thorugh query? as i have many entries and i cannot hardcode values

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can also use ST_MakePoint which is probably cleaner as you don't have to concatenate latitude and longitude values as text. Use it in conjunction with ST_SetSrid to set the coordinate reference system to 4326, eg,

```
Select ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat),4326) from sometable;
```

will return a geometry type. Note the order is lon/lat (x/y), a cause of lots of confusion, due to people saying lat/lon in everyday speech.

ST_GeomFromText is generally more useful when you have a geometry in Well-known text (WKT) format, eg,

```
Select ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0))', 4326);
```

If your data is actually in the form ((-79.4609576808001,43.9726680183837)) and you don't want to split it up as I suggested above, the correct format to use use with ST_GeomFromText for a point is:

```
Select ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-79.4609576808001 43.9726680183837)', 4326)
```

where the SRID is optional, but recommended.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_Known_Text for more information.

Comment: thanks for answer can u tell me one thing i want to get data from DB so i want to put select statement in st_geomfromtext() like select st_geomfromtext(select statement). is ther anyway to do this?

Comment: @MuneemHabib. yes, there is, but could you clarify how your data looks -- do you really have a columns that looks like ((-79.4609576808001,43.9726680183837)) or do you have a separate column for latitude and longitude values.

Comment: sir st_geomfromText will convert only one point to geometry. Is there any way to convert multiple points to geometry? Yes i have data as ((-79.4609576808001,43.9726680183837)) and i have convert this data to POINT(-79.4609576808001 43.9726680183837) format

Comment: @MuneemHabib If your column is now in the form POINT(-79.4609576808001 43.9726680183837) and lets say this column is called pt and is of type varchar, and you have a geometry column you want to populate called geom, then you can just run: update "erpAssets" set geom=ST_GeomFromText(pt) and that will update the whole table.

Comment: sir i have column as alias which have POINT(-79.4609576808001 43.9726680183837) how shoudl i use st_geomfromtext to get geometry of all points?

Comment: I thought I just answered that or I have misunderstood something? select st_geomfromtext(colname) from tablename. colname is the column that contains your  POINT(-79.4609576808001 43.9726680183837)

Comment: Whats the reason everyone is recommending `ST_GeomFromText ` instead of [`ST_PointFromText`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_PointFromText.html)?

Comment: ST_PointFromText is simpy a subset of ST_GeomFromText. You could use it in this case, but you won't gain anything from it. Personally, I prefer [ST_MakePoint](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html), except you have to wrap that with ST_SetSrid, whereas with the text versions, you can set that directly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ST_GeomFromText is expecting a string, not a variable. [Is ST_GeomFromText better than providing direct geometry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086684/is-st-geomfromtext-better-than-providing-direct-geometry) mentions the function is immutable.

This question gives one way of building a string from variables.
[Insert PostGIS Object (e.g. ST_GeomFromText) from row variables in plpgsql script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433513/insert-postgis-object-e-g-st-geomfromtext-from-row-variables-in-plpgsql-scrip)

So it looks like Chris Traver's solution should work for you:

```
ST_GeomFromText('POINT(' || row_data.longitude || ' ' || row_data.latitude || 
 ' ' || row_data.altitude || ')', 4326)
```

So you just need to access the x and y portion of the point.
`ST_X(point)` and `ST_Y(point)` will respectively return the x and y coordinate of a point in PostGIS, but I don't know what data type `region` is, and I don't think it a point type.

Comment: region datatype is string itcontains 2 points x and y how i should use this points?

Comment: I have check this query 'SELECT ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.064544 42.28787)');' and this is running f9

Comment: Does your column really look like this?((-79.4609576808001,43.9726680183837)) or is it more like 79.4609576808001,43.9726680183837. This will determine whether it is better to use ST_Makepoint or ST_GeomFromText, possibly in the way midfield99 suggested first.

Comment: sir i have successfully convert to POINT(-79.4609576808001 43.9726680183837). Now just tell me 1 last thing ST_GeomFromText will convert only point. is there any way to convert multiple point?