# PostGis invalid geometry

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am having issue with postgis geometry.

Following is my query

```
SELECT ST_GeomFromText(trim(data))
FROM (SELECT replace(concat(concat('''POINT',concat(trim(TRAILING ')' FROM concat('(',trim(LEADING '(' FROM ea.region::TEXT)::TEXT) ),')')),''''),',',' ') as data from "erpAssets" as ea where ea.id=326816 )as foo;
```

It is giving error which is as follows:
SQL error:

> ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry HINT:  "'P" <-- parse error at
>   position 2 within geometry In statement: SELECT
>   ST_GeomFromText(trim(data)) FROM (SELECT
>   replace(concat(concat('''POINT',concat(trim(TRAILING ')' FROM
>   concat('(',trim(LEADING '(' FROM ea.region::TEXT)::TEXT)
>   ),')')),''''),',',' ') as data from "erpAssets" as ea where
>   ea.id=326816 )as foo;

When i run simple inner select query it gives me point data when i copy this data and put it in st_GeomFromText() then it is running f9. but when i use above query then it is giving me parse error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23509690/how-to-convert-point-text-to-geometry), `ea.region` appears to be text that looks like:

```
((-79.4609576808001,43.9726680183837))
```

The parse error or your processed `data` is obvious if you look at the value of your attempt:

```
'POINT(-79.4609576808001 43.9726680183837)'
```

which is invalid because it has single quotes on each side. This is the same as attempting:

```
select ST_GeomFromText($$'POINT(-79.4609576808001 43.9726680183837)'$$);
```

Furthermore, the query can be simplified by using `||` instead of `concat`, and just using `substr` if you know to only trim off the first and last characters:

```
SELECT
  region,
  'POINT' || replace(substr(region, 2, length(region) - 2), ',', ' ') AS correct,
  ST_GeomFromText('POINT' ||
    replace(substr(region, 2, length(region) - 2), ',', ' '), 4326) AS geom
FROM
  (SELECT 326816 AS id,
    '((-79.4609576808001,43.9726680183837))'::text AS region) AS ea
WHERE ea.id=326816;

-[ RECORD 1 ]-----------------------------------------------
region  | ((-79.4609576808001,43.9726680183837))
correct | POINT(-79.4609576808001 43.9726680183837)
geom    | 0101000020E610000018F8A45480DD53C05C69B86280FC4540
```

Comment: thanks for answer but st_GeomFromText('Point'), it accepts Point with in single quotes. If i remove single quotes then it is giving error

Comment: In SQL, single quotes are required for string constants like 'POINT', however you were also including a quote character in the string itself. This is very clear in the parse error message and in the `data` value from your previous attempt as I have shown above.

Comment: thanks sir now its clear, one last thing. St_GeomFromText is working for one point only. i have multiple point how i should make st_geomFromText work for more then 1 point

Comment: This is basic SQL. Put your table name in the `FROM` part and remove the `WHERE` filter.